# AspNetCore OpenIdConnect Error Handling

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

In my MVC Core project, after authenticating against Azure AD, I check to see if the User exists in my application database. If User does not exist I want to throw an exception and redirect to my Home/Error page.

Instead, the redirect code in `OnAuthenticationFailed` results in a redirect loop and finally quits with the error:

> Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request
>   headers is too long.

```
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        app.UseCookieAuthentication();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
           ...
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                {
                    ...                       
                    upn = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;

                    MyDbContext db =
                    new MyDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

                    if (db.Users.FirstOrDefault(b => (b.UPN == upn)) == null)
                    {
                            throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException("You are not registered to use this application.");
                    }                       
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

This has been resolved. By default the `HomeController` has `[Authroize]` attribute set on the entire class so the redirect could not reach the `Error` action without being authenticated.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have resolved this issue. Any concerns, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Thank you for posting the update! Helped a ton!